# How to perform a mysql statement with dynamic count of where clauses in java.sql

Tags: mysql, jersey

I have a jersey java server and a mysql server:

I send a `POST` with an `ArrayList<Long>` to the server. Then I want to do a select like `...where long OR long OR long....`

Is there an elegant way to solve this problem and not to do always a single select in a for loop?

How can I form a sql-statement with dynamic count of where clauses?

Thank you very mutch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `OR` multiple times, you can use `IN` with the `where` clause in the SQL query.
You can read `ArrayList` object in a loop and set the where clause values.

**JAVA code snippet**:

```
int paramCount = list.size();

StringBuilder sqlSelect = new StringBuilder( 1024 );
sqlSelect.append( "select x,y,z from my_table " ); 

if( paramCount > 0 ) {
  sqlSelect.append( "where long_column in ( " );
  for( i = 0; i < paramCount; i++ ) {
    sqlSelect.append( ( i > 0 ? ", ?" : "?" );
  } // for each param
  sqlSelect.append( " )" );
} // if list is not empty

// make the prepare statement (pst) with the above sql string
// ...

// now set the parameter values in the query
int paramIndex = 1;
if( paramCount > 0 ) {
  for( i = 0; i < paramCount; i++ ) {
    pst.setLong( paramIndex++, ( (Long)list.get( i ) ).longValue() );
  } // for each param
} // if list is not empty
```