# How to update MySQL database using only non empty user input fields

Tags: php, mysql, forms, post

I have a database where I am trying to update based on some user input form. I am using the following codes to update MySQL database.

```
$query = "UPDATE supervisorupdate SET shift1PinCount =?, shift2PinCount =?, shift3PinCount =?, shift4PinCount =? WHERE Code=?";

$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);

if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $query)){
   echo "updating supervisorupdate table when click save button SQL statement failed";
}else{
   mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"iiiis", $shift1PinCount, $shift2PinCount, $shift3PinCount, $shift4PinCount, $Code);
   mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
   $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
}
```

Here `$shift1PinCount`, `$shift2PinCount`, `$shift3PinCount`, `$shift4PinCount` are some `$_POST` variables that I getting from the user input form

**What I need**

Lets say if user didn't key in anything in the `$shift1PinCount` field, the query shouldn't update anything into MySQL database's `shift1PinCount` column.

**My Problem**

With the query that I have, it always update all the MySQL columns no matter if user keyed in something or left it empty in the user input form. Does anyone knows how to do it?

Comment: 1. while reading request params, check which of them can be used in the update query. 2. then re construct sql statement. 3. pass input data and execute.

Comment: can you please give me some example codes to refer?

Comment: If user didn't key anything, what should be the default value?

Comment: @tcadidot0 If user didn't key in anything in the userform, then database shouldn't change anything for that respective field. Means that if there is some value already present in database, it should remain the same

Comment: The problem I see with this appoach is how can the user empty an input field and update it in the database. Best way is to put the existing data in the <form> and update all fields comming back from the $_POST

Comment: @Henry There is no problem. User can leave empty fields and update database. The condition here is, if user kept some field empty, then database's data will remain the same. I have some other issue with putting existing data in the form. That is why I can't do that

Comment: If the information always has a value you're good to go this way.

Answer (score 1):

**Try to put if condition on post data like**

```
<?php
     if(isset($_POST["shift1"]))
{

    $query = "
        Update product SET shift1 = ?,
    ";
    if(isset($_POST["shift2"]))
    {
        $query .= "
         shift2 = ? ,
        ";
    }
    if(isset($_POST["shift3"]))
    {
        $query .= "
         shift3 = ? ,
        ";
    }if(isset($_POST["shift4"]))
    {
        $query .= "
         shift4 = ? ,
        ";
    }
    $query .=" Where Code=?";
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);

    if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $query)){
       echo "updating supervisorupdate table when click save button SQL statement failed";
    }else{
       mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"iiiis", $_POST["shift1"], $_POST["shift1"], $_POST["shift1"], $_POST["shift1"], $Code);
       mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
       $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: This is only checking one possible combination. There can have many situation such as `$_POST['shift1PinCount']` not set or `$_POST['shift2PinCount']` not set or `$_POST['shift1PinCount']` and `$_POST['shift2PinCount']` not set and so on. That is a big and huge chunk of code. I believe there is other easy or tidy way to do this.

Comment: @Anu use **&&** , **||** operator and then check it........... like this :
`if(isset($_POST['shift1PinCount']) && isset($_POST['shift2PinCount']) )`

Comment: Yes that is okay to do like that. But what I mean is, there are four such inputs with a lot of combinations and codes. There should be much faster or efficient ways to do it. I am just waiting for such a solution

Comment: @Anu : Does combinations will affect this ? as you only need to check four $_POST value. Other way from my point of view is to create array of input fields and check it through loop

Comment: Yes ofcourse it will affect. For example, take the scenario you posted. It is only checking the condition `if(isset($_POST['shift1PinCount']))`. Lets say if `$_POST['shift1PinCount']` and `$_POST['shift2PinCount'] not set, it will not execute your code. So I need to write all possible combination code in order to satisfy all conditions. And there are so many combinations.

Comment: Another way could be use your method and write 4 separate queries for the 4 `isset` condition. Each query focus and update only one field at each time. But again this is not an efficient way of doing I guess

Comment: @Anu Yeah efficient way is to do with 1 query. Your solution is to use If conditions on query and at the end merge all the result

Comment: Thank you. After the discussion with you, I got it done. Although it is not efficient, for my situation I can use it for now. I am upvoting your answer

Comment: @Anu Thank you !.... I am updating my answer maybe that will help you to get the idea of your solution

Comment: I checked it. Although it is the solution you need but not the efficient way. I hope you will get the idea from my solution

Comment: I have a doubt about this. with this solution this line will always static `mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"iiiis",`. So lets say if one of the post variable is not set, there will still be `iiii`. How does it handle this? Also I guess, you need to add `!empty` condition too

Comment: @Anu Yeah this will work if it is not in prepared statement my bad

Comment: okay. I want to use prepared statement since it better safeguard SQL injections. So for now, I am going with the solution I posted. I hope someone can give a better way of doing. For my case it is only 4 variables. If there are so many variables, definitely I can't used the method I posted

Comment: yeah prepared statement is better I am not saying don't use it. Well I will work on that and hopefully get the solution

Comment: @anu I try if conditions on bindParam and it works same if conditions which i put in query. Although its better to get  `$_POST` first in variables and use that variables in if conditions. Sample Code
`if(isset($_POST["shift1"]))
$vStatement->bind_param('s',$_POST["shift1"] );`

Answer (score 1):

After tried some methods, I am able to get it done by doing the following way. But I am sure there are much better way to do. Please post if someone know a better way of doing

```html
if(isset($_POST['shift1PinCount']) && !empty($_POST['shift1PinCount'])){
    pinCountUpdateQuery("shift1PinCount", $_POST['shift1PinCount'], $Code);
}

if(isset($_POST['shift2PinCount']) && !empty($_POST['shift2PinCount'])){
    pinCountUpdateQuery("shift2PinCount", $_POST['shift2PinCount'], $Code);
}

if(isset($_POST['shift3PinCount']) && !empty($_POST['shift3PinCount'])){
    pinCountUpdateQuery("shift3PinCount", $_POST['shift3PinCount'], $Code);
}

if(isset($_POST['shift4PinCount']) && !empty($_POST['shift4PinCount'])){
    pinCountUpdateQuery("shift4PinCount", $_POST['shift4PinCount'], $Code);
}
```

Then use the following function

```html
function pinCountUpdateQuery($shiftPinCountDb, $shiftPinCountUserForm, $Code){
  global $conn;
    $query = "UPDATE supervisorupdate SET ".$shiftPinCountDb." =? WHERE Code=?";
        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
        if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $query)){
            echo "updating supervisorupdate table when click save button SQL statement failed";
        }else{
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"is", $shiftPinCountUserForm, $Code);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**pseudo code**:

```
param1 = req get param1
param2 = req get param2
.
.
paramN = req get paramN

$query = "UPDATE supervisorupdate SET "
bool can_be_updated = false
# now add prepare the rest of sql for inputs
for range of params count to be updated
    if current param is valid then
        if not can_be_updated then
            can_be_updated = true
        end if
        if current param number is > 1 < param count then
            query += ", "
        end if
        query += 'current param name = ?'
    end if
end loop

# now complete sql
if can_be_updated then 
    $query += ' WHERE Code=?'
    .
    .
    # bind sql with valid param inputs like one of the following
    # option 1: if only 2 are valid
    call rel_mysql_func_to_bind_params($stmt,"iiiis", valid param 1, valid param M, $Code);
    # or
    # option N: if all are valid
    call rel_mysql_func_to_bind_params($stmt,"iiiis", $shift1PinCount, $shift2PinCount, $shift3PinCount, $shift4PinCount, $Code);

    # now execute your stmt
    relevant_mysql_func_to_execute($stmt);
else
    # what else you want, perform here
end if
```

**Others**:
Refer to similar requirement answered for Java @
[How to perform a mysql statement with dynamic count of where clauses in java.sql](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22883003/767881)

Comment: This is a poor idea to give pseudo-code mixed with poorly written mysqli. This is much longer than the actual code would be.

Comment: @Dharman I think Ravinder Reddy's approach can be used with php mysql way of coding although it can be complicated (May be it can be done using an easier algorithm). And after all, I think solution to this problem is only by constructing queries based on the conditions

Comment: @anu: as hammer also mentioned that executing multiple fields of a record in single attempt would be good. otherwise, you end up executing 1 to N number of update calls on a single record. try the approach i mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use `COALESCE()` as follows:

```
UPDATE supervisorupdate SET 
    shift1PinCount = COALESCE(?, shift1PinCount),
    shift2PinCount = COALESCE(?, shift2PinCount),
    shift3PinCount = COALESCE(?, shift3PinCount),
    shift4PinCount = COALESCE(?, shift4PinCount)
WHERE Code = ?
```

This phrases as: if no value was given for input for a given column, retain the existing value.

Comment: I tried this, but the database's respective column value is updating to '0' with respect to the empty user input field.